# Why String.indexOf check failed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

From this famous [high-voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript) I've find an effective way to check if a string contains another string or not with [String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
var abcde = "abcdefg";
var abc = "abc";
alert(abc.indexOf(abcde) != -1);//return true
```

But when I try to do like this:

```
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript";
var s = "stackoverflow";
alert(s.indexOf(url) != -1); //**return false,but I think it 'should' return true!**
```

I'm curious that why a more complex which contains symbol or slash <kbd>/</kbd> *seems to be failed*. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string you search is the parameter, not the receiver.

Change

```
alert(s.indexOf(url) != -1);
```

to

```
alert(url.indexOf(s) != -1);
```

(and you should also use [console.log](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) instead of alert, for your own comfort)